# Jenkins override Parameter value on a Build Step

Tags: android, batch-file, parameters, jenkins, continuous-integration

I need to decide value of a parameter after the latest version of the code checked out thats why i cant use the existing parameter types.

First thing came into my mind was to defining some empty parameter and then overriding its value inside a build step but i could not managed to do it. I tried windows batch commands like that but the value is not overriden anyway.

In a Windows Batch Command build step, i tried to override the parameter VERSION with the following command

```
set VERSION = "2.1"
```

What i am actually trying is adding version name of an android application to the filename reading from AndroidManifest.xml file.

I also wrote some groovy script as following, to get the version name,

```
def pattern = ~/(?m)android:versionName="([^"]*)"/
File file = new File("AndroidManifest.xml")

regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(file.text)
println matcher[0][1]
```

Comment: Why can't you use the "this build is parameterized" option?

Comment: build parameters are defined before the code is checked out, my parameters value is dependent with the latest version of the code.

Comment: Ok, Which versioning system are you using? Git, svn, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the [Envinject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)? It will let you set parameters from a file, and one of the use cases shown on the web page is to inject parameters after SCM checkout.